# Partial refresh/reload in a repeatcontrol of a xpage

Tags: custom-controls, xpages

I've created a customcontrol with a repeatcontrol showing a panel for each related document (of a notes doccollection). The xpage arround the cc is bound to a maindocument.
The panel in the repeatcontrol contains some inputfields, a fileuploadcontrol, a filedownloadcontrol and an action-button.
If the user select a file in the fileuploadcontrol an press the button, then the document bound to the panel is saved and an notesagent replace the old attachment with the new selected.
After that, the current panel should be refreshed, so that the filedownloadcontrol shows the right attachment for download. But only the current panel should be refreshed, not the complete xpage or other panels in the repeatcontrol (context.reloadPage is not the solution I need).
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put all your code in the button and then partial refresh the panel in the button.

But I suspect that the question refres to that you cannot save a file attachment using partial refresh. which is true. there are a few solutions to this, like using an iframe. do a google search on that

Comment: update: in Domino 9.0.1 you can upload images using partial refresh

Answer (score 0):

An example for using iframes is described at the [Domino development wiki](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/revisions/AE30A98F64CC3CE6852575940061703B?OpenDocument). The mentioned approach is used in the [Lead Manager X](http://www.openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/ProjectLookup/Lead%20Manager%20X) example at OpenNTF.

However, depending on whether or not that fits your needs, you may also consider using the [XPages Exension Library](http://extlib.openntf.org/), specifically the *Dynamic Pages* therein.

Answer (score 0):

did you try giving the partial refresh id for the panel containing the document?  If that doesnt work.. get the handle of the particular panel in clientside and refresh it.  Panel inside repeat can be identified with its index.